# カウント変数を用いた変数の作成

Tags: python, tkinter

tkinterで、18個の図形の作成時に、管理用のためにオブジェクトに付随した変数、object0 ~ object 17 を作りたいと思っています。
そのため、カウント変数`i`を用い、オブジェクトの作成時に一緒に変数を割り当てようと考えました。

```py
for i range (0,17):
　"object"i = canvas.create_rectangle :……
```

という形で変数を作成しようとしましたが違いました…
正規表現の活用なども出来ないかと考えましたが、上手く思い浮かばず。

どのようにすれば実現できるかご存知の方がいらっしゃれば、ご教示いただけると幸いです。
私がそもそも実現不可能な事をしようとしているならば、このアプローチは断念して、1行ずつ　object1 = …　、object2 = …　と変数を作成しようと思います。

Comment: FAQみたいなものである程度の人が思い付く発想ですね。こちらの記事およびそのコメントに示したリンク等を参照してください。[Google colabのループ内で変数名に連番をつける方法はありますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/88267/26370), [Pythonで連番のオブジェクトを宣言する際の良い書き方について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/59579/26370), [execで連番の変数名を動的に生成するのに代る方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/36330/26370)

Comment: やはり既出の内容でしたか…リンクの案内までしていただき、ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 2):

惜しいですね。Pythonの「リスト」を使って表現してみると次のようになります。ぜひ、お手元の環境で実行してみてください。`objects` がリストです。

```py
objects = []

for i in range(18):
  objects.append("element " + str(i))

print(objects)
```

`append` は、配列に要素を追加するメソッドです。引数をTkinterのオブジェクトにすれば、やりたいことが達成できるはずです。

参考：[リスト型 (list) - 組み込み型 — Python 3.10.4 ドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists)

Comment: 実行できました。丁寧に説明していただき感謝です。これでやりたかった事ができそうで安堵しています。未熟者ですが精進していきます！

Comment: それはよかったです。[自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) もご覧になってくださいね。

Answer (score 1):

execコマンドを使うことで、コードにカウント変数の値を埋め込むことができます。

```
for i in range(0,17):
  exec("object{}= canvas.create_rectangle……".format(i))
```

`exec`と`format`の説明として、

- `exec`は、引数として与えられた文字列をPythonのコードとして実行します。
- `format`は、引数（今回は `i`の値）を`{}`の位置に代入します。

これで、object0 から object17 までの変数を作れるはずです。

Comment: 補足：今後、このプログラムを書いた人が「そうだ！ユーザーが好きな名前の `object` を作れるようにしよう」と考えて、`i` などにユーザの入力を受け取れるようにした場合を考えてみます。普通の人は、`bike` などと入力して、 `object_bike` 変数が作られることになります。一方、ちょっと変わった人は、 `i` に `=None; print("hoge"); a` などと入力するかもしれません。こうすると、 `exec` が実行するのは `object=None; print("hoge"); a=canvas...` となり、プログラマーの意図に反して `hoge` と表示されてしまうのです。もちろん、`print` されるだけならたいしたことはないのですが、同じ書き方で `open()` を使ってファイルを読み出したり消したりすることもできてしまいます。セキュリティホール（脆弱性）の出来上がりです。このようなリスクがあるので、一般的に、`exec` や `eval` といった関数の使用には注意が必要とされています。逆に、このような関数を使って柔軟な実装を行うメタプログラミングという領域もあることにはありますが、やはり特殊なケースです。

Comment: なるほど、おっしゃる通りですね。教えてくださり、ありがとうございます！